# Notepad++ proper encoding settings

Tags: notepad++, encoding, character-encoding, special-characters

Notepad++ can't display characters like ⊰ http://graphemica.com/%E2%8A%B0 . What is the best settings to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to ensure that the font you are using for your current Notepad++ theme contains the character in its mapping. For the specific example you cited, that character should display just fine with [Cambria Math](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/family.aspx?FID=360).

Depending on your use case, you may want to consider defining a custom style theme for Notepad++ to use.

Comment: I checked it, the font already installed. And I have no problem with these characters with other programs like Excel.

Comment: @user2132188 What I'm saying is that you have to make sure your current font is set to Cambria Math (or another font supporting that specific glyph) for that character to appear. I'm certain if you highlighted it in Word or Excel, it will interpret the font as Cambria Math.